# hosts.allow, hosts.deny : One rule per service?

Tags: linux, security, hosts.deny

In quite a few [places](https://www.smartdomotik.com/2015/02/09/using-etchosts-allow-and-etchosts-deny-to-secure-unix/) (some [old](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/10/using-tcp-wrappers-to-secure-linux.html), some [recent](https://www.ostechnix.com/restrict-access-linux-servers-using-tcp-wrappers/)) it's stated that the tcp-wrappers configuration files `/etc/hosts.allow, /etc/hosts.deny` allow only **one rule per service**.

This looks wrong to me, I write many `sshd: <IP SUBNET>` lines in my `/etc/hosts.allow` and it seems to work as expected (Centos 7).

Am I misunderstanding the affirmation above, or perhaps it's something that
was true in older versions of tcp-wrappers, or what?

Comment: Also note that I tested this in Ubuntu 18.04 and it also appears to allow multiple lines for the same service, though I could also not find an authoritative source that said this was allowed.